# Add field to array without index defining - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

**Thanks guys. I was wrong about my way. Please don't post anymore.**

I had some trouble with my array.

I generate my array in this way:

```
private function _getMenuBar(){
    $data = array();
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM df_menubar_table WHERE visible = 1 AND parent = -1 ORDER BY priority");
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
      $data[count($data)] = array(
        "menu" => array(
          "title" => $row['title'],
          "url" => $row['url'],
          "name" => $row['name'],
          "selected" => 0
        )
      );
    }
    return $data;
  }
```

As usual array will feed like

array[0] = menu => array(title,url,name,selected);

but I want to not define `$data[**count($data)**]` as index and define 'menu' as index. And CodeIgniter doesn't support something like this for passing to views. Therefore I need to key be the **menu**.

It means:

array[0] = menu => array(title,url,name,selected);

To:

array['menu'] = array(title,url,name,selected);

BTW, I tried += but It just stored the last row.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I tried your way it turned to this:

I tried it. But it turned to this:

```
array(1) {
  ["menu"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["menu"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(8) "اصلی"
        ["url"]=>
        string(30) "http://localhost/dreamfactory/"
        ["name"]=>
        NULL
        ["selected"]=>
        int(0)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Whats bad with the last array example? That it only has one item but you want all items?

Comment: It's turning whole arrays in one single field :). They're separated.

Comment: That "single field" is actually an array of 5 items. I won't call that single. You will have it available as an array in `$menu` in your template. How do you need it in your template, I think an array is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some type of unique identifier. Adding multiple items to array['menu'], with no unique identifier, will cause the last/newest item to overwrite the ones before. You can have an array set up like below.

```
 Array 1:
 Array (
   [menu] => Array (
     [0] => Array (
       [title] => Title
       [url] => URL
       [name] => Name
       [selected] => Selected
     )
   )
 )

 Array 2:
 Array (
   [0] => Array (
       [title] => Title
       [url] => URL
       [name] => Name
       [selected] => Selected
   )
 )
```

The last one can be with or with out the menu item.

Code will look like below (simplified)

```
 private function _getMenuBar(){
  $data = array();
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM df_menubar_table WHERE visible = 1 AND parent = -1 ORDER BY priority");
  $countRows = 0;
  foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
   $data[$countRows] = array(
      "title" => $row['title'],
      "url" => $row['url'],
      "name" => $row['name'],
      "selected" => 0
    );
    $countRows++;
   }
  return $data;
 }
```

Comment: I want to do this but CodeIgniter when passes array to a view, in the view you should use field names as variable like `$menu`. But I don't know how should I use a numeric identifier.

Comment: add a variable $countRows = 0; before the foreach, and then at the end of the foreach put $countRows++; $countRows will be the unique identifier

Comment: Ok I test it now. BTW! if I do it, It's just like the `$data[count($data)]`. huh? All my problem is CodeIgniter does now passes array itself to the view If it wasn't be like that I could use `$data[$i]["menu"][...]`.

Comment: essentially yes but this way it does not rely on if the data array is empty or not and always starts at 0. count($data) uses what ever data may be in it. creating a blank array does not always mean it is blank, I have found in some cases it can sometimes have one item in it and can through everything off.

Answer (score 0):

do an `array_shift()` on $data. That way, you get rid of the `array[0]` wrapper. Is this what you meant? If not, pleace be more explicit